# timespan + specific time with python schedule package

Tags: python

I want to schedule my Skript ever hour at :45 an run this betwenn the hours of 7 a.m. and 10 p.m. I found the schedule package that seems to meet my requirements but I was unable to combine all criteria. My best to solutions would be to run this in 16 different version like:
`schedule.every().day.at("07:45").do(Crawlen)`
`schedule.every().day.at("08:45").do(Crawlen)`

the other option would be:
`schedule.every().monday.hour(":45").do(Crawlen)`
but then it would run also throu the night.

Am i missing some functions i could use?